# How to use template in static function?

Tags: java

I want use a base class for all Singleton class. The base class would be:

```
public class SingletonBase<T> {
    private static T instance;

    public static T getInstance() {
        //......
    }
}
```

So that every Singleton can extends it to obtain the `getInstance` function.

In C++, I can use Marco, but in java , the template `T` cannot be use in static function or member.

So , how to achieve it in java ?

The above is just a example , do not discuss the `Singleton` 's usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply declare the generic type within the method declaration:

```
public static <T> T getInstance() {
    //......
}
```

Comment: what about the static member?

Comment: I don't think static members can have a generic type, since they are shared across all instances of the class, i.e. `SingletonBase<Integer>` and `SingletoneBase<String>` are going to have the same field, but it cannot be both `Integer` and `String` at the same time (since there is only one instance of that field).;